# Why can’t we use GraphQL just with Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, graphql, apollo, relayjs

I’m wondering why people doesn’t seem to use GraphQL jus with Redux.

I’ve never used GraphQL before but I’d like to start a new project, but neither Apollo and Relay doesn’t convince me. Currently I’m creating an app that use react and redux and “old fashion” rest api. And I love the idea of redux that it store whole informations about my app in one place.

And now, as far as I understand both Apollo and relay does something similar but they use separate store and in both we mixing the logic and view even more than with just React, both of these things (another store and mixing code) seems to be a bit messy. The advantage is caching, am I right?

So why can’t we just send the query as we used to with normal rest api and put the data to the redux store (maybe try to store some kind information about sync for optimisation).

Sorry if there are thing that i missed, I’m new here and I’m not a pro, it’s why I ask some people that probably has more experience that me :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**"store some kind [of] information about sync for optimisation"** becomes a very hard problem when you have lot of interdependent entities.

Also, structuring the client side state is a hard problem in large applications. The rules of thumb, considered as best practices, in the redux community are that you need to normalize and remove redundancy in your redux state tree when inserting and denormalize them when using in components.

The libraries like relay and apollo want to own the state they manage so that they can remove this responsibility of normalizing/denormalizing the data, and managing the cache (as much as possible) to a significant extent from end users while still providing them low level control when they need to.

This is a fairly sophisticated problem because different components may depend on partial models eg. `NoteSummary` component may need only `title` and `tags` fields, the `NoteDetails` component will need `description` and `comments` too.

If you manage the redux state yourself you will have to write code for the following, when `NoteDetails` component is presented:

1. If a Note is not already present in the redux tree, fetch the required fields using a graphql query.
2. If a Note is already present, but not all the required fields are present, create a graphql query for the missing fields, and then fetch them by querying the graphql server.
3. If a Note is already present, and has all the required fields, just use the local version.

This becomes a lot more complex when we have entities which have dependencies on each other, or when realtime collaboration or subscriptions are involved.

GraphQL libraries attempt to solve **all of the above** in a **very network efficient manner**. Using react-apollo or relay your component can declare what all it needs and the underlying library, will intelligently figure out what and how much to fetch.

This is philosophically similar to how you write react components: In your render method you declare what your final component hierarchy should look like (given present state) and the library (react) figures out what changes are to be made to the DOM.

You should evaluate if your use case benefits from this kind of network efficiency and if so, whether you are willing to invest time putting in the effort required to learn GraphQL and the ecosystem around it.

If a redux store and a few ajax calls suffice for your use case, it can be a much simpler setup.

If you decide to go full on with GraphQL and Apollo, you might want to not have redux at all. You can use [apollo-link-state](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/links/state.html) and manage all your data (local or remote) using graphql Queries and mutations. Then from the perspective of your components it becomes irrelevant whether some data is remote or local.

---

Having said all the above, if you really want to **just** use redux along with graphql without any additional libraries like Relay you can use [Apollo client](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client) directly. You can dispatch [thunks](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) from components, then in your thunks, you can make graphql queries directly using the Apollo client, and once you receive the response you can put that data in the tree in the tree using another action dispatch.

If this sounds more complex, it is because it simply is.

Comment: Very good answer. I can totally relate: Over one year GraphQL in production and I never looked back to redux. Why should I worry about the store state, content or shape if a library can do this for me? Just today a backend engineer in my team said: Now that I'm learning React, GraphQL totally makes sense!

Comment: Really a well thought answer. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: This is a good answer but one thing keeps me puzzled. How do I use Apollo with a native app, where the state is persisted (like in redux-persist) and offline first is important. How do I fetch all releant data for the app and still use small queries per component without having a normalized state like in apollo.